# Why am I getting an uncaught TypeError when I pass a function to a child component in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a small chunk of a larger codebase. But I believe this is the only relevant part needed for this question.

I have two components `DataSeries` and `Sector`. The `DataSeries` component is rendered by another parent component. And the `Sector` component is rendered by the `DataSeries` component. I'm passing a function as a property from `DataSeries` to `Sector`. But when I try to call that function from `Sector` I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.someFunc is not a function` error. And I'm not really sure why. Any help?

Here is the code.

```
var Sector = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {text: '', count:'', opacity:'arc'};
  },
  formatNumber: function(num, digits) {
      //irrelevant function
      return num;
  },
  render: function() {
    var outerRadius = this.props.width/2.2;
    var innerRadius = this.props.width/3.5;
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(outerRadius)
        .innerRadius(innerRadius);
    var data = this.props.data;
    var center = "translate(" + arc.centroid(data) + ")";
    var nameCenter = "translate(0,0)";
    var countCenter = "translate(0,50)"
    var color = this.props.colors;
    var formattedCount = this.formatNumber(this.state.count, 1)
    return (
      <g onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver} onMouseOut={this.onMouseOut} onClick={this.onClick}>
        <path className={this.state.opacity} fill={color[this.props.ikey]} d={arc(this.props.data)}></path>
        <text fill={color[this.props.ikey]} stroke={color} fontSize="27px" transform={nameCenter} textAnchor="middle">{this.state.text}</text>
        <text fill={"#868686"} stroke={color} fontSize="25px" transform={countCenter} textAnchor="middle">{formattedCount}</text>
      </g>
    );
  },

  onMouseOver: function() {

    this.setState({text: '', count:'', opacity:'arc-hover'});
    this.setState({text: this.props.name, count:this.props.data.value});
    console.log("Inside onMouseOver")
    this.props.someFunc();
  },
  onMouseOut: function() {
    this.setState({text: '', count: '', opacity:'arc'});
  },
  onClick: function() {
    //Do something on click?
  }
});

var DataSeries = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    width: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    height: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    color: React.PropTypes.array,
    data: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  },
  randomFunction: function() {
    console.log("Random Function")
  },
  render: function() {
    var color = this.props.colors;
    var data = this.props.data;
    var width = this.props.width;
    var height = this.props.height;
    var pie = d3.layout.pie();
    var result = data.map(function(item){
      return item.count;
    })
    console.log(result)
    var names = data.map(function(item){
      return item.name;
    })
    var sum = result.reduce(function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0);
    var position = "translate(" + (width)/2 + "," + (height)/2 + ")";
    var arcs = (pie(result)).map(function(point, i) {
      return (
        <Sector 
           data={point} 
           ikey={i} 
           key={i} 
           name={names[i]} 
           colors={color} 
           total={sum} 
           width={width} 
           height={height} 
           someFunc={this.randomFunction}/>
      )
    });
    return (
        <g transform={position}>
        {arcs}
        </g>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `map`, the context represented by `this` changes. So, currently, inside your `map` call, `this.randomFunction` is actually `"undefined"`.

So, to use the `Sector`'s context of `this` that has your function in it, you need to bind `Sector`'s `this` to the `map`'s anonymous function.

```
var arcs = (pie(result)).map(function(point, i) {
  return (
    <Sector 
      data={point} 
      ikey={i} 
      key={i} 
      name={names[i]} 
      colors={color} 
      total={sum} 
      width={width} 
      height={height} 
      someFunc={this.randomFunction}
    />
  )
}.bind(this));
```

What this is doing is setting the context of `this` inside of the anonymous function to the `this` from `Sector`.

Comment: This works. Thank you. Such an obvious lapse of judgement on my part that I can now see once you pointed it out.